# Microsoft word search for past tense

Tags: ms-word

I need to find all the past-tense words in Microsoft Word documents and update them to present tense. Is there any nice "search for past tense" tool that I can use?

Search all verb-forms is not as useful as I'd like it to be, I can do that, but then I need to know all the verbs in all the documents.

My problem is that I have 30'ish 400+ page documents that have mixed verb forms, it'd be tedious enough doing the search with a perfect tool, but my current solution of searching through each verb in each document is almost unworkably tedious.

---

Maybe just a past-tense dictionary, I can write something that uses a dictionary to find words to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that an English version of this program would be just as tedious to write as it would be to manually correct the documents.

Programmers often fall prey to this kind of thinking.  We've all done it - faced with an odious manual solution, we write a program or script that ends up taking as long or longer to get right than it would have to get a shovel and do it manually.

Break the problem into parts.  Start with a grammar for English that can distinguish the verbs from all the other words in every case.

Get a dictionary of verb tenses for the verbs you'll need.

Walk the abstract syntax tree and substitute the past tense verbs for their present tense counterparts.

You don't say what computer language you're comfortable with.  If it's Java, I'd recommend looking at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org).  It's a wonderful parser/generator for Java.

When I say "write a program", I'm thinking that you'd start with something like this.

Recognize that getting a significant portion of the job in one go might be worth it.  But no matter what, you'll have proof read each and every one to make sure that the code did the right thing or risk a public gaffe.

There's another possibility: [crowd source](http://www.crowdsource.com/) it.  Give one document each to 30+ people and ask them to do the laborious job for one document.  Better yet, break those into parts and use more people.  Parallelism is your friend here.

Comment: I like the crowd-sourcing idea, but it won't work for me, my documents cannot be shown to others.

Comment: You're screwed, then.  Are you an organization of one?  Is there no one else in your org that can help?  What good do you accomplish by implementing this change?  I don't see it.

Comment: Me writing a program is a possible solution for me, but it probably isn't worth it (worth it for the company in the long run, but not for me with my current deadlines).

Comment: No choice, then.  Can't write a program; can't crowd source it.  Better start now.

Comment: There are hundreds of people that will use the documents, but access to the docs is limited to groups that are all on tight schedules. -- And the reality is that there will be little good done by this change, just a more standards compliant document that very few will read.

Comment: Ugh. This seems like a tool idea that is useful enough, and technically easy enough that it should have been done by now, but I think you're right. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at a program called VisibleThread. From what I understand, it will perform content analysis for you and find areas where past-tense is used.